# Saving while-loop data into vector

Tags: matlab, vector, while-loop

I have this while loop which works well and gives the correct output data but as it ends it only saves the latest datapoint, how can I save every loopdata into a vector?

```
t0=0.15; % Initial time
v0=46.5285; % Initial velocity
h0=3.4896; %Initial height
dt=0.001; % Timesteps/Precision
m=0.05; %Mass
g=9.81; % The gravitational constant

Velocity2=46.5285;

t = t0;
while Velocity2>=-20
Velocity2=hastighet(acceleration(0,m,g),t,v0,t0);
Height2=hojd(acceleration(0,m,g),t,h0,v0,t0);
 t=t+dt;
end
```

Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
t = t0;
velocityData = [];
heightData = [];
timeData = [];
counter = 1;

while Velocity2>=-20
    Velocity2=hastighet(acceleration(0,m,g),t,v0,t0);
    Height2=hojd(acceleration(0,m,g),t,h0,v0,t0);
    velocityData(counter) = Velocity2;
    heightData(counter) = Height2;
    timeData(counter) = t;
    t=t+dt;
    counter = counter + 1;
end
```